# gfortran "-march=haswell" slower than "-march=core2"

Tags: performance, gcc, x86, gfortran

I run gfortran 4.9.2 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with an Intel Core i5-4570 (Haswell). I compile and execute on this same machine.

Compiling my code (scientific simulation) with

```
gfortran -frecord-marker-4 -fno-automatic -O3 -fdefault-real-8 (...)
         -Wline-truncation -Wsurprising -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow (...)
         -march=core2 -mfpmath=sse -c
```

is about ~30% FASTER than compiling with

```
gfortran -frecord-marker-4 -fno-automatic -O3 -fdefault-real-8 (...)
         -Wline-truncation -Wsurprising -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow (...)
         -march=haswell -mfpmath=sse -c
```

(`-march=native` gives the same result as with `-march=haswell`).

This feels strange/weird to me, as I would expect having additional instructions available should make the code faster, not slower.

First: this a new machine and a replacement of my old one at work so unfortunately:

- I can't test with the previous processor anymore
- It is difficult for me test with another gfortran version than the one installed

Now, I did some profiling with gprof and different `-march=` settings (see [gcc online listing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html)). On this test:

- `core2`, `nehalem`, `westmere` all lead to ~85s
- starting from `sandybridge` (adding the AVX instruction set), execution time jumps to 122s (128s for `haswell`).

Here are the reported profiles, cut at functions > 1.0s self time.

Flat profile for `-march=core2`:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name    
  8.92      6.18     6.18                             __sinl_internal
  8.50     12.07     5.89                             __cosl_internal
  7.26     17.10     5.03                             _mcount_private
  6.42     21.55     4.45                             exp
  6.41     25.99     4.44                             exp2l
  5.08     29.51     3.52                             __fentry__
  3.71     32.08     2.57 35922427     0.07     0.18  predn_
  3.53     34.53     2.45                             log2l
  3.36     36.86     2.33 79418108     0.03     0.03  vxs_tvxs_
  2.90     38.87     2.01 97875942     0.02     0.02  rk4m_
  2.83     40.83     1.96   403671     4.86    77.44  radarx_
  2.16     42.33     1.50  4063165     0.37     0.43  dchdd_
  2.14     43.81     1.48                             pow
  2.11     45.27     1.46  8475809     0.17     0.27  aerosj_
  2.09     46.72     1.45 23079874     0.06     0.06  snrm2_
  1.86     48.01     1.29                             cos
  1.80     49.26     1.25                             sin
  1.75     50.47     1.21 15980084     0.08     0.08  sgemv_
  1.66     51.62     1.15 61799016     0.02     0.05  x2acc_
  1.64     52.76     1.14 43182542     0.03     0.03  atmostd_
  1.56     53.84     1.08 24821235     0.04     0.04  axb_
  1.53     54.90     1.06 138497449     0.01     0.01  axvc_
```

Flat profile for `-march=haswell`:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name    
  6.49      6.71     6.71                             __sinl_internal
  6.05     12.96     6.25                             __cosl_internal
  5.55     18.70     5.74                             _mcount_private
  5.16     24.03     5.33                             exp
  5.14     29.34     5.31                             cos
  4.87     34.37     5.03                             sin
  4.67     39.20     4.83                             exp2l
  4.55     43.90     4.70 35922756     0.13     0.34  predn_
  4.38     48.43     4.53  8475884     0.53     0.69  aerosj_
  3.72     52.27     3.84                             pow
  3.43     55.82     3.55                             __fentry__
  2.79     58.70     2.88   403672     7.13   120.62  radarx_
  2.64     61.43     2.73 79396558     0.03     0.03  vxs_tvxs_
  2.36     63.87     2.44                             log2l
  1.95     65.89     2.02 97881202     0.02     0.02  rk4m_
  1.80     67.75     1.86 12314052     0.15     0.15  axs_txs_
  1.74     69.55     1.80  8475848     0.21     0.66  mvpd_
  1.72     71.33     1.78 36345392     0.05     0.05  gauss_
  1.53     72.91     1.58 25028687     0.06     0.06  aescudi_
  1.52     74.48     1.57 43187368     0.04     0.04  atmostd_
  1.44     75.97     1.49 23077428     0.06     0.06  snrm2_
  1.43     77.45     1.48 17560212     0.08     0.08  txs_axs_
  1.38     78.88     1.43  4062635     0.35     0.42  dchdd_
  1.36     80.29     1.41                             internal_modf
  1.30     81.63     1.34 61800367     0.02     0.06  x2acc_
  1.26     82.93     1.30                             log
  1.25     84.22     1.29 138497176     0.01     0.01  axvc_
  1.24     85.50     1.28 15978523     0.08     0.08  sgemv_
  1.10     86.64     1.14 10707022     0.11     0.11  ec_txs_
  1.09     87.77     1.13  8475648     0.13     0.21  g_eval_
  1.06     88.87     1.10                             __logl_internal
  0.98     89.88     1.01 17765874     0.06     0.07  solgeo_
  0.98     90.89     1.01 15978523     0.06     0.06  sger_
```

You'll notice basically everything seems slower with `-haswell` (even internal functions like sin/cos/exp !).

I can give an example of code, the function `vxs_tvxs`, which consumes 2.73s vs 2.33s:

```
  SUBROUTINE VXS_TVXS(VXS,TVXS)

  REAL VXS(3),TVXS(3,3)

  VTOT=sqrt(sum(VXS**2))
  VH=sqrt(VXS(1)**2+VXS(2)**2)

  if (VTOT==0.) then
    print*,'PB VXS_TVXS : VTOT=',VTOT
    stop
  endif

  sg=-VXS(3)/VTOT
  cg=VH/VTOT
  if (VH==0.) then
    sc=0.
    cc=1.
  else
    sc=VXS(2)/VH
    cc=VXS(1)/VH
  endif

  TVXS(1,:)=(/ cg*cc, cg*sc, -sg/)
  TVXS(2,:)=(/   -sc,    cc,  0./)
  TVXS(3,:)=(/ sg*cc, sg*sc,  cg/)

  RETURN
  END
```

Seems quite an innocuous function to me...

I have made a very simple program

```
PROGRAM PIPO
REAL VXS0(3),VXS(3),TVXS(3,3)
VXS0=(/50.,100.,200./)
VXS=VXS0
call cpu_time(start)
do k=1,50 000 000
  call VXS_TVXS(VXS,TVXS)
  VXS=0.5*(VXS0+TVXS(1+mod(k,3),:))
  VXS=cos(VXS)
enddo
call cpu_time(finish)
print*,finish-start,VXS
END
```

Unfortunately, in this test case, all `-march` settings end up with about the same time requirement.

So I really don't get what is happening... plus, as we see from the previous profile, the fact that even internal functions are costing more feels very puzzling.

Comment: Can you disassemble both versions and post assembly for the part which is taking most of the time? `gcc` will save assembly code if run with the `-S` option, I don't know if `gfortran` is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I can actually do that, nevertheless if that helps, the simulation itself is about 15k lines of code, and it's mostly scientific calculations. Basically, algebra makes up the most of the computing time, if that helps.

Comment: There are plenty of asm experts who frequent this site, and if you can profile your code to find the "hotspot" and disassemble it, chances are very high that someone will figure out the answer for you. If it's just "it's a big program and I can't give any details or show any code", you won't get an answer. In that case, you might have better luck on a different site; this site is specifically for asking questions which do have a clearly defined answer.

Comment: What version of gfortran are you using?  If it is not a recent version, I would suggest upgrading to 4.9.2 and to try again.  If you can locate a piece of code where most of your time is spent via profiling (via the `-pg` option and `gprof`) and can show a piece of code that is pessimized, I would suggest sumitting a bug report to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ . This way, the gcc maintainers will learn about this issue, and it has a good chance of being fixed (even higher if it is a regression, e.g. if the identical options produced better code earlier).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it in the opening post. It's 4.9.2 already.

I'll try to see if I can identify a specific part of code that gets noticeably slower with the -haswell flag.

Comment: Did this ever run slower with an older version of gfortran?

Comment: If you post the disassemblies I could analyse what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks harold. I am not familiar with how to produce relevant disassembly code. I see that I should use the -S at compile time, but then ? Also, I'll make a few additional tests, notably with the sole vxs_tvxs function which is quite simple. If I can reproduce the same behavior on a test program that is simply looping vxs_tvxs a million times with different values, it should narrow it down to a gcc/gfortran issue (and also greatly simplify the study as the code to work with would be only a few lines instead of >20k)

Comment: A file with a .s extension should appear, by the way please also add `-masm=intel` to the command line. It'll be best if it's a small loop yes, otherwise I'll probably get lost in tons of code not relevant to this issue

Comment: A program simply looping vxs_tvxs does not yield any difference between the two flags :(

Comment: Sounds like mixing AVX instructions (your program) and SSE instructions (libm), which can have a bad penalty (missing vzeroupper maybe?).

Comment: Hmmm, and what could I do about that ? Just in case, note I'm not a software developer - 'just' a technical engineer with his scientific simulation, coding in Fortran. If the solution involves some assembly-related manipulation, that would be completely uncharted territory for me (which is okay, only don't be afraid of overexplaining possible instructions :)).

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I wondered the same thing after ruling out micro-fusion of indexed addressing modes (https://godbolt.org/z/CPUvD5 show gfortran 4.9.4 doesn't use any for the OP's MCVE, at least when targeting Linux instead of the OP's Windows with gcc4.9.2).  But it's not being auto-vectorized.  128-bit (and scalar) AVX instructions shouldn't need `vzeroupper` before a `call sqrt`, assuming it was already in a "clean upper" state.  Maybe if something dirtied the upper 128, then yeah nothing would ever clean it.

Comment: @ParkerLewis: Try compiling your short MCVE with `-fno-math-errno` so `sqrt` can inline as `vsqrtsd`, so there are no function calls inside the loop.  (And no spill/reload of XMM registers around the call).  If it's still slow on a Haswell CPU, that means it's something other than AVX state transitions, because executing 128-bit AVX instructions is fast whether you're in State B (dirty upper halves of YMM regs) or State A (clean uppers), with the only possible penalty on the first AVX instruction in the function. [see this for HSW vs. SKL penalties](//stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780))